# Appending lists in lambda

Tags: list, lambda, f#

This works in F# Interactive:

```
let (list:(int * int) List) = []
list @ [(40, 60)];;
```

This doesent work in my program:

```
let rMouseEvent = 
    form.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> list @ [(args.X, args.Y)]))
```

Can someone explain why, and help me solve this?

The error says:
This expression was expected to have type
  unit
but here has type
  'a list -> 'a list

Comment: What compile error do you get or what else fails?

Comment: Sorry, update the post. It's a compile error

Comment: Are you sure that's the error [I'd have expected something more like a complaint that it has type `(int * int) list`]? Which expression is it highlighting? The diagnosis in Lee's answer seems essentially correct though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler should not return a value, at present it returns an `int * int list`. You could ignore it using ignore:

```
let rMouseEvent = form.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> list @ [(args.X, args.Y)] |> ignore)
```

although this is not very useful. If you want to add an item to `list`, you could change it to a `ResizeArray`:

```
let r = new ResizeArray<int * int>()
let rMouseEvent = form.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> r.Add((args.X, args.Y)))
```

alternatively you can use a ref:

```
let (r: (int*int) list ref) = ref []
let rMouseEvent = form.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> r := !r @ [(args.X, args.Y)])
```

Comment: Why isn't it useful? And what does ResizeArray compared to this way?

Comment: @PontusMagnusson - It isn't useful because you're creating a new list and immediately discarding it. `@` creates a new list from two input lists, it doesn't modify either argument list. If you want a mutable list, use `ResizeArray`.

Answer (score 2):

The compile error you get indicates that the event handler was expected to return `unit` - i.e. no value at all - but you're trying to return a `(int * int) list`. The expected return type indicates that the caller isn't going to look after the value you return for you, so you need to store any values you change yourself.

If you want to stick with using lists, then make your original list into `ref`:

```
let list : (int * int) List ref = ref []
```

and then do something like:

```
let rMouseEvent = 
    form.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> list := !list @ [(args.X, args.Y)]))
```